# Understanding a definition of infinitely often

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

My textbook states that the definition for $A_{n}$ occurs infinitely often is:

$\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} A_{n} = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(\cup_{m \geq n}A_m) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\cup_{m \geq n} A_m)$

I don't understand how we get the second equality. Is it just because another way to look at the limit is just an infinite intersection? And we don't have a similar equality for  $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} A_n = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\cap_{m \geq n} A_m)$ because we have an infinite union so we couldn't write that as a  limit, is that right?

Comment: We *do* have $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m\geq n}A_m=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigcap_{m\geq n}A_m.$$ For more about this topic, the [Wikipedia article about set-theoretic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit) might be helpful.

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you